# Use of spark.core.SpriteVisualElement in a mobile application

Tags: apache-flex

The question is: Is it a good practice to use SpriteVisualElement instead of UIComponent to create custom components? The reason being I can't add Sprite or FlexSprite as direct children of View and I see that UIComponent is quite heavy then SpriteVisualComponent from code point of view.

I searched extensively to confirm if there are certain examples elsewhere which shows use of this control as the base to create custom controls but could only find [this](http://hulstkamp.com/articles/flex-spritevisualelement). So actually I was little less confident about weather this is Ok or not.

Below is the supplement information:

1. Nature of application: Educational game application for children
2. Target platform: Mobile device (currently only Android platform)
3. Application environment: Flex SDK4.6 with AIR 3.8. Blank Spark application with spark.components.ViewNavigator. PureMVC framework used. Multiple Views to contain custom components which mostly use graphics package to draw themselves and to draw child controls within them (This is where I actually extend SpriteVisualElement for custom drawing as well as containing and displaying other custom controls).

Please suggest me if what I am doing is a good practice for a mobile app or not.

Thanks in advance and regards,
Sachin.

Comment: It depends what the component needs to do.  I've used SpriteVisualElement as the base for FXG Images and Animated library assets created in Flash Pro. My general rule is; do what you need to do and re-evaluate when you run into performance problems.  Using a "lighter" component is fine but I'd try to avid reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

I use it often as SpriteVisualElement is lighter. I always try to use lighter things if it's fit my needs so I think it's a good practice especially for mobile development.